# Guide me in Start developing my first Hybrid Application in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, web-applications, hybrid-mobile-app

Hi to all Cool developers. 
I am here for a helping guide that able to make me start my first Hybrid web+mobile application.

**My Project:**

I am going to build my final Project in Computer Science. The project i choose is a website that will serve as a platform for all Educational related info like Universites, Admissions, Scholarships, Carrers, Free Courses, Instituite recommednder e.t.c. Reference website: http://www.eduvision.edu.pk/

**Technologies I have in mind to work on:**

My main focus is to built it in using Node, express and Mongodb(Mongoose).

**My Confusions:**

As my website is heavily database oriented, what is best way to built it?

How to make it interactive and easily navigate?

How can I make it Hybrid? I know React native is used for this. But what's the procedure? Will I have to keep this in mind while developing my web application?

What frameworks and libraries I should use?

**It would be a huge help. 
Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

this look similar to me.hi anyways!you wanna choose is a website that will serve as a platform for all Educational related info like Universites, Admissions, Scholarships, Carrers, Free Courses by using mean stack ok its a new user friendly technology.to be honest you can build a website called (college management system).
where in this the students in the college will be a part of this website and all the details of the students will be in database when they register.and with this application it is helpful for the students to view their attendence and updates which were given by the college management.by using a framework like bootstrap,material design you can interact and easily navigate.as coming to the main question that you want to choose a website that will serve as a platform for all Educational related info like Universites, Admissions, Scholarships, Carrers, Free Courses.this is perfectly applicable.where universities can post Admissions,Scholarships can be posted in this website which is useful for the students.and also they will be aware of the attendence.which can be viewed by them daily and their will be no bluffing in it.and universites which can also update their information if any emergency required.to let the students know immediately.
as i already mention bootstarp and material design are the best framework to use and additionaly i am advising you to use visual code (IDE) for developing the project.because it is easy to use and user friendly.and you can also refer library called Quackit which gives best experience for you.and it is the best project for you to build in final year.